# Как сделать "плавный" вырез в секции снизу?

Tags: html, css

Всем привет, встала задача заверстать такой вот вырез для секции:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

не пойму как его сделать, к тому же, хотелось бы, чтобы эта "деталь" была отдельна от родителя:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

т.е. чтобы я мог крутить её через `transform: rotate()`

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.section {
  position: relative;
}

.section__image {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 90vh;
  background: yellow;
  display: block;
}

.cut {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 10vh;
  background: pink;
}

.cut::before {
  content: "";
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: block;
  background: green;
  position: absolute;
  top: -50px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.cut::before * {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.cut::before .section {
  position: relative;
}

.cut::before .section__image {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 90vh;
  background: yellow;
  display: block;
}

.cut::before .cut {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 10vh;
  background: pink;
}

.cut::before .cut::before {
  content: "";
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: block;
  background: green;
  position: absolute;
  top: -50px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<section class="section">
  <div class="section__image"></div>

  <div class="cut"></div>
</section>
```

Comment: а сделать волну из 2ух элементов?
с плавным радиусом?

Comment: https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/KjjWPo